# Speed up MySQL Update - InnoDB

Tags: c++, mysql, performance

I wouldn't think an update of 22*1000 values of type DOUBLE should take ~4 seconds.  However that is what I am getting.  The following is query is done 22 times.  Perhaps this is actually on par?  It doesn't satisfy my speed requirements then.

`UPDATE [some table] SET [some column] = (CASE WHEN [column1] = i THEN [some number]`

concatenated through i=1:1:1000, ending with `END);`

This statement takes ~4/22 seconds.

Remedies I have tried:
Lock table before update, and unlock after.

Thoughts to help(yet to try):
Reduce update into smaller update queries.

Additional Info:
Engine: InnoDB,
C++ Connector

**EDIT 1**

Code Excerpt:

```
Query ="LOCK TABLES CANS_SQL.SortingIndices WRITE;";
stmt = con->createStatement();
bool LOCKBIT = stmt->execute(Query);

delete stmt;
Query.clear();

Query = "UPDATE SortingIndices SET " + Objects.at(Typ).GetMetricNames().at(ObjMetIndex) + "_KVector = ( CASE  ";
for (int k = 0; k<kvector.size()-1; k++)
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(InsertCount<KvectorInsertPos.size())
        {
            if (KvectorInsertPos.at(InsertCount)==k)
            {
                Query += "WHEN Sort_ID = " + std::to_string(k+1+InsertCount) + " THEN " + std::to_string(KvectorInsertVal.at(InsertCount)+InsertCount) + " ";
                InsertCount++;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    Query += "WHEN Sort_ID = " + std::to_string(k+1+InsertCount) + " THEN " + std::to_string(kvector.at(k)+InsertCount) + " ";
}
while(true)
{
    if(InsertCount<KvectorInsertPos.size())
    {
        if (KvectorInsertPos.at(InsertCount)==kvector.size()-1)
        {
            Query += "WHEN Sort_ID = " + std::to_string(kvector.size()+InsertCount) + " THEN " + std::to_string(KvectorInsertVal.at(InsertCount)+InsertCount) + " ";
            InsertCount++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    else
        break;
}
Query += "WHEN Sort_ID = " + std::to_string(kvector.size()+InsertCount) + " THEN " + std::to_string(kvector.at(kvector.size()-1)+InsertCount) + " END ) ";
stmt = con->createStatement();
stmt->executeUpdate(Query);

delete stmt;
```

**EDIT 2**

Example Query:

```
Query = "UPDATE SortingIndices 
    SET X_Centroid_Sort_Index = (CASE 
         WHEN Sort_ID = 1 THEN 1.4324 
         WHEN Sort_ID = 2 THEN 4.234 
         WHEN Sort_ID = 3 THEN 324
         ...
         WHEN Sort_ID = 1000 THEN 232.4 END);
```

Comment: instead of using case statement, have the values stored in temp table and use it in your update query. It may improve performance

Comment: Do you have a where condition on your update statement? From what is shown you are updating every single row in the table with every call. If you are updating every row in the table, is there still a need to run it 22 times?

Comment: It is updating every single row for a given column. Some computations are done before each update. For the 22 columns. For modularity, they cannot be combined into one update.

Comment: could you post your code please?

Comment: Sorry, but could you show an example of final `Query` you are trying to run?

Comment: You seem to be updating every column in every row, one column at a time. Consider a matrix, your updating A1, A2, ..., AN, then B1, B2, ... BN and so on, snaking through each value. Very much a Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm. If you want any type of performance, you'll want to update a row only once. If you choose modularity, then you may have to sacrifice performance.

Comment: @JRD it seems strange not to be able to update a entire column the same way.  That is what I am trying to do.  Rows don't necessarily change together, but columns do.  I am leaning to leaving a RDBMS all together and storing these tables as structures in memory.

Comment: Yes, you may want to think of a different architecture. Typically, a RDBMS works in units of rows, and row sets. You may want to look at columnar databases which optimize storage/retrieval at the column level.